# Android @TargetApi return

Tags: android, annotations

I'm using a method with boolean return type for api 19 while my app supports min sdk 15, what will the method return incase the api is less than 19 ?

```
@TargetApi(19)
    public static boolean isFeatureXEnabled(Context context) {

    some logic

    return true/false;
}
```

what do I get in return for API <19 when calling?

classInstance.isFeatureXEnabled(context);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's understand `@TargetApi(19)`

You are using a feature which is not available on minimum SDK so

```
Compiler : you cannot use this feature , it is not supported by min sdk

You: i know what i am doing so hush , take this @TargetApi(19)

Compiler : so now it is your responsibility to check the API level and call this function accordingly
```

> what will the method return incase the api is less than 19

If the code inside this function is not supported by minsdk then most likely a crash otherwise your result of your logical calculation

you can do something like this

```
@TargetApi(19)
public static boolean isFeatureXEnabled(Context context) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
         some logic
         return true/false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**@TargetApi**

> Indicates that Lint should treat this type as targeting a given API level, no matter what the project target is — https://developer.android.com/reference/android/annotation/TargetApi.html

It means it is just used by Lint to hide/suppress the warning. It has ho effect in the return value.